# Rotating a Axe Model in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

So, For Context im trying to emulate kind of like throwing an axe, when you throw an axe it spins and spins and spins vertically.However, I got the spinning part right but the axis that is at, is not right the axe it should be facing vertically not facing you, i will post a gyazo link just so u can see how it spins right now. https://gyazo.com/99eaa8c1b5b3ce22205148509e115b14

Ive tried a couple things, ive tweend it, i thought that would work, as tweening it i can do it infinitley, But the result was it being still. I also tried pivoting it, But because of my courtine. Sometimes it wouldnt even go through
Heres The roblox code

````lua
local function ZodiacMove(plr,Mouse)
    local TestingCourotine = coroutine.create(function(Handle)
        while true do RunService.Stepped:Wait()
            print(Handle)

            Handle.CFrame = Handle.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0,0,math.rad(10))
            if Handle.Parent == nil then break end
        end
        print('the axe has vanished :sob:')
    end)
    local ZodiacProjectile = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Axe:Clone()
    local Handle = ZodiacProjectile:FindFirstChild("Blade")["Blade Tip"]
    print(Handle)
    local ZodiacProjectilePivot = ZodiacProjectile:GetPivot()
    ZodiacProjectile:PivotTo(ZodiacProjectilePivot * CFrame.new(math.rad(10),0,0))
    coroutine.resume(TestingCourotine,Handle)
    ---TweenInfoGoals.CFrame = Handle.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0,0,math.rad(360))
    --local ZodiacProjectileTween = TweenService:Create(Handle, tweenInfo,TweenInfoGoals)
    --ZodiacProjectileTween:Play()
    local OverParams = OverlapParams.new()
    OverParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    OverParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = {workspace.Baseplate, plr.Character, plr.Character:GetChildren()}
    local HumanoidRootPart = plr.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    local BV = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
    BV.Parent =  Handle
    ZodiacProjectile.Parent = HumanoidRootPart
    BV.Velocity = HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.LookVector * 100 
    BV.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
    ZodiacProjectile:PivotTo( HumanoidRootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -1))
    Debris:AddItem(ZodiacProjectile,2)
end```
````